# What does adding an IP to a URL do?

Tags: ip, http

This is probably an easy question to answer, I just do not know how to search for it. My basic question is how is going to a url with specified URL different than going to direction to the url?

IE how what is the difference between these two:

http://128.28.122.122/

http://128.28.122.122/https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first URL is connecting to `128.28.122.122` then asking for the webpage name `/`.

The second URL is connecting to `128.28.122.122` then asking for a webpage named `/http://stackoverflow.com/` on that server, what that server does with that request is up to the service that is hosting the website.

Based on the usage the 2nd URL is likely is some kind of proxy server, so the server will do whatever it needs to do to the request first (Log it, grab a cached copy of the page, etc..)  then the server will request `http://stackoverflow.com/` and forward the result back to you.